# App icon appears for a few seconds but then turns blank

Tags: ios

I've not changed anything regarding the app icon but today my app has started behaving in a strange way which is if I install/run via XCode then move the app to the background the icon for the app is displayed on the desktop for a few seconds then disapepars and is replaced by a white icon, and it keeps on doing this repeatedly.
I can't get it to stop doing this and can't get the icon to permanently display correctly. I'm using XCode 13.0 on hardware, never seen this issue before today, but like I say I haven't changed anything. It also behaves this way if I create an archive and instlall the app that way.
Doing things like cleaning/delete derived data/re-start the iPhone don't fix it.

If I checkout an older version of the code from git, a week ago for example, then the same thing is happening for that too, yet that was fine a week ago.

I've even tried deleting and re-installing XCode but its still occuring.

UPDATE: I tried a different iPhone and it works at expected, its something with the iPhone itself causing the issue. But deleting the app/restarting the iPhone does not fix whatever the issue is. What could the problem be with the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the minor iOS version update for your phone.

But till then if you just want to verify that if your app doesn't break for users, Install your app on the same iPhone via TestFlight. If it's not breaking in this case. I guess you are good to go for release to users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this weird behaviour as well. I've tried to fix it with reinstalling / unpairing / restarting etc but no luck.

Tested on my iPhone and iPad... it is a bug for sure.